# overlays uncover and hide text

Tags: beamer, overlays, pause

How I can implement the following "Algorithm" in one particular slide ? 
I hope is clear want I want to do

```
 \documentclass[serif]{beamer}

\begin{document}
% one Particular Slide 
\begin{frame}

Some Text here 

1. then I want this text to appear 
2. Then I want to hide 1 and appear 3
3. Some other text here

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the [beamer documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf)? Sections 3.9 and 3.10 explain how to use overlays.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't say what should happen to 2, I assume it should be visible throughout, along with the introductory text. If not, you can adjust this quite easily:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  Some Text here
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<2> then I want this text to appear
    \item Then I want to hide 1 and appear 3
    \item<3> Some other text here
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: enumeration with overlays]

As mentioned in comments, reading the manual will enable you to modify things as you prefer.